# How to add a row number column in linq

Tags: linq

i am trying to add a row number in a linq query, i have the next code:

```
return (
                from p in dbContext.pedidos
                where p.Fecha == DateTime.Now
                orderby p.Fecha
                select new PedidosModel()
                {
                    IdPedido = p.IdPedido,
                    Fecha = p.Fecha,
                    IdCliente = p.IdCliente,
                    Observaciones = p.Observaciones,
                    Estatus = p.Estatus
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: How are you planning to use row number ? You can convert the data `ToArray()` and use index + 1 as a row number.

Comment: Yup, i am planning to display the order number of the day and use the resultset in a DataSource

Comment: In this case just use index.

Comment: I'll search how to aproach your comment. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two argument version of select on the client side to add the row number:

```
return (
        from p in dbContext.pedidos
        where p.Fecha == DateTime.Now
        orderby p.Fecha
       ).ToList()
        .Select((p,r) => new PedidosModel()
            {
                IdPedido = p.IdPedido,
                Fecha = p.Fecha,
                IdCliente = p.IdCliente,
                Observaciones = p.Observaciones,
                Estatus = p.Estatus,
                RowNumber = r
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Note: If the `pedidos` objects are large, retrieving them and then projecting may not be as efficient as projecting twice:

```
return (
        from p in dbContext.pedidos
        where p.Fecha == DateTime.Now
        orderby p.Fecha
        select new PedidosModel()
        {
            IdPedido = p.IdPedido,
            Fecha = p.Fecha,
            IdCliente = p.IdCliente,
            Observaciones = p.Observaciones,
            Estatus = p.Estatus
        }
    ).AsEnumerable()
     .Select((p, r) => new { p, RowNumber = r })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Kinda late to complement this answer but I forgot to mention I was using SQL Server CE and it doen't support RowNumber but in SQL Server work like a charm

Comment: @Abel this doesn't use the SQL Server `ROWNUMBER` function but rather the LINQ To Objects two argument `Select`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You can mark the answer as approved (checkmark) if it worked for you.